# Shift minipage containing tabulars left

Tags: tables, minipage

I want to draw three tables next to each-other horizontally.

EDIT: In response to comment have dropped the `minipage`.

\centering seems to stack them on top of each other, is there a way to force a single line?

Code here & screenshot below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

    \centering
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c|c|c|c|}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$AA$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$AB$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$BB$} \\\cline{2-4}
            $AA$ & $P_{11}^{AA}$ & $P_{12}^{AA}$ & $P_{13}^{AA}$ \\\cline{2-4}
            $AB$ & $P_{21}^{AA}$ & $P_{22}^{AA}$ & $P_{23}^{AA}$ \\\cline{2-4}
            $BB$ & $P_{31}^{AA}$ & $P_{32}^{AA}$ & $P_{33}^{AA}$ \\\cline{2-4}
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c|c|c|c|}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$AA$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$AB$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$BB$} \\\cline{2-4}
            $AA$ & $P_{11}^{AB}$ & $P_{12}^{AB}$ & $P_{13}^{AB}$ \\\cline{2-4}
            $AB$ & $P_{21}^{AB}$ & $P_{22}^{AB}$ & $P_{23}^{AB}$ \\\cline{2-4}
            $BB$ & $P_{31}^{AB}$ & $P_{32}^{AB}$ & $P_{33}^{AB}$ \\\cline{2-4}
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c|c|c|c|}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$AA$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$AB$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$BB$} \\\cline{2-4}
            $AA$ & $P_{11}^{BB}$ & $P_{12}^{BB}$ & $P_{13}^{BB}$ \\\cline{2-4}
            $AB$ & $P_{21}^{BB}$ & $P_{22}^{BB}$ & $P_{23}^{BB}$ \\\cline{2-4}
            $BB$ & $P_{31}^{BB}$ & $P_{32}^{BB}$ & $P_{33}^{BB}$ \\\cline{2-4}
        \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's a normal paragraph indent so you could use `\noindent`  or wrap in a `center` environment etc also you don't need the minipages, you could just use three tabular

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Have edited the post to drop minipages. `\centering` seems to stack them, is there a way to force a single line? I also tried `\noindent` but it only seemed to move them left by a very small amount.

Comment: they are placed like letters you have one word space between each tabular (from the newline) and they do not fit on a line so just as if you have `one two three` it line breaks at the second space if needed. you could use `\small`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't increase the width of the text block, some of the following, not mutually exclusive, measures may yield success:

- Switch from a `tabular` environment to an `array` environment. The default amount of intercolumn whitespace is smaller for `array` environments is smaller than that for `tabular` environments. Plus, making this switch would let you get rid of ninety [90!] `$` symbols.
- Reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace, which is governed by the `\tabcolsep` and `\arraycolsep` macros. Their default values are `6pt` and `5pt`, respectively, in many document classes.
- Change `\begin{array}[t]{c|c|c|c|}` to `\begin{array}[t]{@{}c|c|c|c|}`, to lop off `\arraycolsep` whitespace.
- Switch to a smaller font size. The `\small` and `\footnotesize` directives bring about 10% and 20% linear font size reductions, respectively.

The following screenshot and minimum working example shows the combined effect of implementing all four of these ideas.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt} % default value: 5pt
$\begin{array}[t]{@{}c|c|c|c|}
    \mc{} & \mc{AA}  & \mc{AB}  & \mc{BB} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    AA & P_{11}^{AA} & P_{12}^{AA} & P_{13}^{AA} \\\cline{2-4}
    AB & P_{21}^{AA} & P_{22}^{AA} & P_{23}^{AA} \\\cline{2-4}
    BB & P_{31}^{AA} & P_{32}^{AA} & P_{33}^{AA} \\\cline{2-4}
\end{array}$\hfill
$\begin{array}[t]{@{}c|c|c|c|}
    \mc{} & \mc{AA}  & \mc{AB}  & \mc{BB} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    AA & P_{11}^{AB} & P_{12}^{AB} & P_{13}^{AB} \\\cline{2-4}
    AB & P_{21}^{AB} & P_{22}^{AB} & P_{23}^{AB} \\\cline{2-4}
    BB & P_{31}^{AB} & P_{32}^{AB} & P_{33}^{AB} \\\cline{2-4}
\end{array}$\hfill
$\begin{array}[t]{@{}c|c|c|c|}
    \mc{} & \mc{AA}  & \mc{AB}  & \mc{BB} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    AA & P_{11}^{BB} & P_{12}^{BB} & P_{13}^{BB} \\\cline{2-4}
    AB & P_{21}^{BB} & P_{22}^{BB} & P_{23}^{BB} \\\cline{2-4}
    BB & P_{31}^{BB} & P_{32}^{BB} & P_{33}^{BB} \\\cline{2-4}
\end{array}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - I greatly appreciate the additional explanations. This is my first TeX project.

Comment: @user3234710 - you’re most welcome